# Data not representative of population, remove some data or acknowledge error

Tags: sampling, error

I am trying to do analysis for a research project. The sample that was collected doesn't properly represent the actual population in the country. For the data in the project, we have that 19% of the survey respondents are car owners and 81% are not, when in the population we are looking at only around 4.3% people in the country are car owners. The reason is that originally only car owners were wanted for the survey but we found that majority of the respondents were not, so we shifted our hypotheses to work with the data. (The non car owners offered insightful reasons as to why they weren't interested or were interested in car ownership as well) Should I just report the large sampling error of -14.7% or should we remove some of the data when looking for correlations and dependence so that it is representative of the population? Any help is so appreciated!